# Error with working with QT QHttp

Tags: qt

i tried to use QHttp in my project but it gives me a strange error. here is my complete QT project .

http://shirazitco.ir/QHttp.zip

Comment: Please see the FAQ on how to ask questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `QHttp` any more, it's deprecated.

Use `QNetworkAccessManager` instead.